# My PHP generated CSV file is saving as a PHP file

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I've learned how to create CSV files from MySQL data from another StackOverflow question. My problem is, for some reason when I call this code, it tries to save a file called `index.php` (which is the current page). Inside the `index.php` file my data from the table is there, separated by commas. I'm guessing I have a small typo somewhere, but after playing with the code I cannot find it. Thanks to anyone who can help.

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * from tbl_email");
if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
  header ("Content-type: application/csv Content-Disposition:\"inline; filename=messages.csv\"");
  echo "REF #,Company,Name,Email,Message,Date\n";
  while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $companyname = mysql_query("SELECT company FROM tbl_users WHERE user_id ='$row[1]'");
    $datname = mysql_fetch_array($companyname);
    echo"$row[7],$datname[company],$row[2],$row[4],$row[5],$row[6]\n";
  }
  die();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need multiple `header()` calls rather than one call which supplies multiple headers on a single line, and I believe the most appropriate mime type for a CSV is `text/csv`.

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=messages.csv");
```

And more commonly, we would use `Content-Disposition: attachment` to force a download.

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=messages.csv");
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks. Is there a reason why you have to split the two, just out of curiosity?

Comment: @user1470755 `header()` sends a single header to the output stream with the appropriate linebreak following.  Content-type and Content-Disposition are two different headers, not two parts of the same header, and must therefore be sent separately.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll accept your answer in a couple minutes as it will not let me right away

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
header('Content-type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="messages.csv"');
```

Notice that the value for filename is not encased correctly with double quotes. Try to use single quotes in php, this will save you alot of trouble. ;)

Have a look at http://www.techcoil.com/blog/php-codes-to-tell-browsers-to-open-the-download-dialog-box-for-users-to-download-a-file/ to learn more about telling browser to download your file.